# Spring boot get @value within a class extending a dependency

Tags: spring-boot

Folks, am trying to access config properties from within a class that I've extended from a dependency. Apparently the config class is returning a null pointer in my implementation class (CustomUtil).

pom.xml

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.utilapp</groupId>    //3rd party library that I need to use
        <artifactId>util-lib</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

The BaseUtil is from the dependency. CustomUtil is a bean in my SpringBoot App & am overriding the method as below to check the key from the config property ignoreKeyList .

```
package com.myapp
...

@Component
public class CustomUtil extends BaseUtil {
    @Autowired
    private ClientConfig clientConfig;    // This returns null!

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldExcludeFromList(String key) {
        return this.clientConfig.getIgnoreKeyList.contains(key);    // their library/util excludes certain keywords from the content being formatted
    }
}
```

Config class in my SpringBoot App.

```
package com.myapp
...

@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
public class ClientConfig {
    @Value("${myapp.ignorekeys}")
    private List<String> ignoreKeyList;

    ...
    ...
}
```

Main class in my app.

```
package com.myapp
...

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyClientApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyClientApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Service implementation class in my SpringBoot App.

```
package com.myapp
import com.utilapp.formatters.FormatBuilder;
import com.utilapp.formatters.TextFormatter;
...

@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Autowired
    private ClientConfig clientConfig;    // works here!

    public String formatContent(String content) {
        TextFormatter formatter = this.getTextFormatter();
        return formatter.parseAndFormat(content);
    }

    private TextFormatter getTextFormatter() {
        return FormatBuilder.custom()    // FormatBuilder is from the dependency
            .withApplication(this.clientConfig.getAppName())    // In their library, the BaseUtil gets instantiated which am extending in my CustomUtil bean
            ...
            ...
            .withIndentSupport(Boolean.TRUE)
            .build();
    }
}
```

Controller in my app

```
package com.myapp
...

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app/v1")
public class StyleController {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @GetMapping("/format")
    public String formatContent(@RequestParam String content) {
        return this.myService.formatContent(content);
    }
}
```

When I debug ClientConfig, it loads the properties from the config file; application.properties in src\main\resources.
But for some reason the ClientConfig is returning null from within the CustomUtil bean. Not sure why!
I originally thought it was due to ordering of bean instantiation. I tried playing around with @Order, @DependsOn, @ComponentScan, @ScanBasePackages etc, but none yields.

Any pointers/guidance please.
Thanks.

Comment: How are you obtaining the reference to the `CustomUtil` instance that has its `clientConfig` variable set to `null`?  Please show the code that causes that bean to be instantiated, and the code that gets access to it and uses it.

Comment: @Steve I've edited my post to showcase the ServiceImpl & Controller. Honestly Component annotation in CustomUtil has no effect. I put it for the sake of Autowired ClientConfig. When formatContent(..) from ServiceImpl gets called via the Rest call flow, shouldExcludeFromList(..) method from CustomUtil gets invoked. I just need to include keys from my app and they need to come through the config, which apparently is null in my case. Clearly my understanding on the instantiation flow handled by Springboot is not up to the mark. Any pointers/suggestions is appreciated. Thanks.